# How to get character after space in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on avatar component in React where I want to get the first character and character after space and give the result to the avatar and display the abbreviated version of the full name. For example:

```
var fullName = ahmed hosny;

//I am able to get the first character like this:

fullName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() // this prints 'A'
```

How can I get 'H' from hosny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex for this.

**For first occurrence**

```js
console.log(fullName.match(/(?<= )./))
// returns [ 'h', index: 6, input: 'ahmed hosny', groups: undefined ]
```

**For all occurrences**

```js
console.log(fullName.match(/(?<= )./g))
// returns array of all characters after space
```

Comment: let me check it out I only want first occurrence of space as i want the Avatar to only contain two characters

Comment: They you should use the first option

Comment: thanks brother it worked is there any way i can convert the result to uppercase ?

Comment: of course, .toUpperCase() after the string will do the job

Comment: tried that before and didn't worked

Comment: how ever i appended toUpperCase() before match() property and it worked thanks man